# How to use Polymorphism, Generics in method signatures?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have a case where I am trying to use polymorphism and method signatures plus casting.

I have an interface like so:

```
<T extends ParentClass> convert(Class<T> clazz, ParameterType type)
```

Where I want to return a child (don't know which type) and in the method I accept another unknown class and a type which is simply an enum. The goal is to take in an object, convert it to another and then hand it back.

I am having issues with my usage and specifically with trying to make tests for this. Here is the implementation:

```
@Override
public <T extends ParentClass> T convert(Class<T> clazz, ParameterType type)

    //Check if clazz is an instance of a specific object and use that specific converter
    if(clazz.isInstance(AnObject.class)) {
        AbObjectConverter anObjectConverter = new anObjectConverter;
        anObjectConverter.convert(castClass(clazz, AnObject.class);
    }
```

The goal is to have more than `AnObject` to convert, so I can send in any object there. Then check which one it is and call the appropriate converter. The class I want to convert is a class (one of many) which share the same parent, hence the class `<T>` in the method.

CastClass simply does this:

```
private static<T> T castClass(Object o, Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.isInstance(o) ? clazz.cast(o) : null;
}
```

I'm trying to make unit tests for this, but how do I do this without errors? I want to make an object that I want to convert, send it to my method and test functionality. For example:

```
@Test
public void testConvertingShouldSucceed() {
    ObjectToConvert object = new ObjectToConvert();
    object.setname("Hello");

    service.convert(object, ApplicationType.CONVERT)
}
```

But this does not work, as I can't cast my object to convert to `T` or whatever, so it complains on the object

How do I actually make use of this to make it compile and work? It feels like it should be simple to use parents, generics and such to send it types I won't know until runtime. Maybe I'm making it needlessly complex.

Comment: I don't understand what your code is trying to do. You call isInstance with a `Class` as a parameter which seems odd. What's the relationship between the `map` function and the first part of your question?

Comment: Your unit test is trying to pass an object to convert, but the `convert` method does not take a data object;  it only accepts a class.  Perhaps the method’s signature should be `convert(Object objectToConvert, Class<T> resultType, ParameterType type)`?

Comment: @tgdavies Sorry, it's supposed to say convert, not map. Basically, I want to accept a class of unknown type(can be one of many), pass it down to the convert method, have a case for each of them and then call an appropriate converter. Then return a different object for each.

Comment: It would be better if you edited your question to show a complete, toy, example of what you want to do. It should be compilable, except for the single compile time error you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

Your method signatures are not correct.

for castClass function, the first parameter you defined is `Object`, but while calling this function you are passing a `Class` instance.

Also the main convert function is taking only `Class` instance in the method definition, where as you are passing `Object` to it in the test case.